# How to create a TimeZone object for a specific timezone? c#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, .net-4.5

I found the exact thing I went to know, and it is so simple (or should be):

TimeZone.GetDaylightChanges() returns exactly what I need:  When the daylight time starts and ends:

To that end, I would want to do:

```
TimeZoneInfo currentTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
TimeZone zone = new TimeZone (currentTimezone);  // Compile error here.

DaylightTime changes = zone.GetDaylightChanges();
```

This, of course won't compile because the constructor of the TimeZone doesn't take a TimeZoneInfo (Wtf?), and I can't figure out how to get the DaylightTime Changes any other way.  I need for someone to set 'timeZoneName' to any timezone and be able to get the start/end DateTimes for whatever timezone they set it to.

**Of Key importance:  The server is running (most likely) UTC, and NOT the timezone that is in 'timeZoneName'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't instantiate a new TimeZone object like that. However, I believe you can get the info you want from the TimeZoneInfo class by looking through the `AdjustmentRules`.

Below are a few methods that I wrote to enable what you want. See the sample usage at the bottom for how it compares to using the `TimeZone` method for the current system time zone.

**UPDATE**

I've modified the code into a couple of classes to help out with the date math, and borrowed heavily from the sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.transitiontime.isfixeddaterule.aspx

```
public static DaylightTime GetDaylightChanges(string timeZoneName, int year)
{
    TimeZoneInfo currentTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);

    var currentRules =
        currentTimezone.GetAdjustmentRules().FirstOrDefault(rule =>
            rule.DateStart <= DateTime.Today &&
            rule.DateEnd >= DateTime.Today);

    if (currentRules != null)
    {
        var daylightStart = 
            GetTransitionDate(currentRules.DaylightTransitionStart, year);

        var daylightEnd = 
            GetTransitionDate(currentRules.DaylightTransitionEnd, year);

        return new DaylightTime(daylightStart, daylightEnd, 
            currentRules.DaylightDelta);
    }

    return null;
}

private static DateTime GetTransitionDate(TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transition, 
    int year)
{
    return (transition.IsFixedDateRule)
        ? new DateTime(year, transition.Month, transition.Day,
            transition.TimeOfDay.Hour, transition.TimeOfDay.Minute,
            transition.TimeOfDay.Second)
        : GetNonFixedTransitionDate(transition, year);
}

private static DateTime GetNonFixedTransitionDate(
    TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transition, int year)
{
    var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
    int startOfWeek = transition.Week * 7 - 6;
    int firstDayOfWeek = (int) calendar.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(year, 
        transition.Month, 1));

    int changeDayOfWeek = (int) transition.DayOfWeek;

    int transitionDay = (firstDayOfWeek <= changeDayOfWeek) 
        ? startOfWeek + (changeDayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek)
        : startOfWeek + (7 - firstDayOfWeek + changeDayOfWeek);

    if (transitionDay > calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, transition.Month))
        transitionDay -= 7;

    return new DateTime(year, transition.Month, transitionDay, 
        transition.TimeOfDay.Hour, transition.TimeOfDay.Minute, 
        transition.TimeOfDay.Second);
}
```

And here's and example of how to use it, compared to using the current TimeZone method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var daylightTime = GetDaylightChanges("Pacific Standard Time", DateTime.Today.Year);
    var dylightTime2 = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(DateTime.Today.Year);
}
```

Comment: Comes up with a time shift of 238 DAYS, so I'm guessing that isn't right.  However, the base code looks like a good start.

Comment: The corrected code is:              return new DaylightTime(daylightStart, daylightEnd, currentRules.DaylightDelta);